# GroupBy Year then take Pairwise diffs except for the head value then Flatten Using Deedle and F#

Tags: f#, f#-data, deedle

I have the following variable:

```
data:seq<(DateTime*float)>
```

and I want to do something like the following F# code but using Deedle:

```
data
|> Seq.groupBy (fun (k,v) -> k.Year) 
|> Seq.map (fun (k,v) -> 
    let vals = v |> Seq.pairwise 
    let first  = seq { yield v |> Seq.head }
    let diffs = vals |> Seq.map (fun ((t0,v0),(t1,v1)) -> (t1, v1 - v0))
    (k, diffs |> Seq.append first))
|> Seq.collect snd
```

This works fine using F# sequences but I want to do it using Deedle series. I know I can do something like:

```
(data:Series<DateTime*float>) |> Series.groupBy (fun k v -> k.Year)...
```

But then I need to take the within group year diffs except for the head value which should just be the value itself and then flatten the results into on series...I am bit confused with the deedle syntax

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the following might be doing what you need:

```
ts 
|> Series.groupInto 
    (fun k _ -> k.Month)
    (fun m s -> 
      let first = series [ fst s.KeyRange => s.[fst s.KeyRange]]
      Series.merge first (Series.diff 1 s))
|> Series.values
|> Series.mergeAll
```

- The `groupInto` function lets you specify a function that should be called on  each of the groups
- For each group, we create series with the differences using `Series.diff` and append a series with the first value at the beginning using `Series.merge`.
- At the end, we get all the nested series & flatten them using `Series.mergeAll`.